# OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Syntax error in JOIN operation."

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, oledb

I am getting this annoying error, but the thing is that I do not use any JOIN operation in my query. Here is the snippet:

````
   ('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\tcmnoc\Desktop\Test.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM ([TradeCloud].[dbo].[Adminlist]')
   Select * from [TradeCloud].[dbo].[Adminlist]```
````

Comment: Why the `(` after FROM?

Comment: jarlh it is required by MS Access Syntax for SQL. If I take it out the error message will tell me syntax error near FROM.
It is quite disgusting to hassle with that syntax. But now the biggest surprise is that now it's telling me about something that is not even present in query.

Comment: That is not true. Parentheses in Access SQL is needed only for more than one `JOIN`. Please provide full code block and not line snippet. We need to see *how* this code is run. Inside SQL Server? Is this part of an [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or [OPENDATASOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/opendatasource-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) query?

Comment: Additionally, the service account for your server instance is HIGHLY unlikely to have permissions to the desktop of a specific user of any machine - even the one on which it is running. Lastly you should be selecting from a sheet or range in your openquery "query" - not a table within some database in your server instance.

Comment: maybe change ( to bracket [

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your snippet derives from an [`OPENROWSET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) query, you are conflating data sources where you attempt to reference an SQL Server table inside an Excel connection. When connecting to an Excel workbook as a data source, you can only reference Excel worksheets, not SQL Server tables.

Therefore, this source is not recognizable: `[TradeCloud].[dbo].[Adminlist]` (correcting the opening parenthesis with square bracket). Instead, connect to an actual Excel worksheet within the workbook connection, placing the named reference outside of the connection string. Below query (after you adjust *mySheet* should work to retrieve Excel-only data):

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Users\tcmnoc\Desktop\Test.xlsx;',
                [mySheet])
```

---

Without fuller context, I consider the following assumptions:

- Maybe Excel is connected to the `[TradeCloud].[dbo].[Adminlist]` table? If so, you need to make a separate, direct connection to the database and schema to access the table (bypassing Excel which is just another client connection).
- Maybe you meant to populate an existing SQL Server table? If so, run the needed append or create-table command then browse its contents:

  ```
  -- APPEND TO TABLE
  INSERT INTO [TradeCloud].[dbo].[Adminlist] (Col1, Col2, Col3, ...)
  SELECT xl.Col1, xl.Col2, xl.Col3, ...
  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                  'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Users\tcmnoc\Desktop\Test.xlsx;',
                  [mySheet]) xl;

  -- CREATE TABLE
  SELECT xl.Col1, xl.Col2, xl.Col3, ...
  INTO [TradeCloud].[dbo].[Adminlist] 
  FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                  'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Users\tcmnoc\Desktop\Test.xlsx;',
                  [mySheet]) xl;

  -- BROWSE CONTENTS
  SELECT * [TradeCloud].[dbo].[Adminlist];
  ```
- Maybe you are attempting to populate an Excel workbook? If so, do note, these commands (`OPENROWSET` and `OPENDATASOURCE`) do not populate an existing Excel workbook but simply connects to external sources (Excel, Access, or other data sources) as a backend to retrieve data.

Comment: Parfait, thanks for your comments and an elaborate answer. My goal is to export the output of the table to Excel workbook. That is why I used that query. From the thrid point of your comment I understood that it is not correct choice. So what should I do in this case?

Comment: My goal is to export the contents of the table periodically to an excel workbook. Please exclude the option that I can do that via SSIS package and run it via MSSQL agent job.

Comment: Please do the necessary [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451). Here, I respond to your attempted code where `OPENROWSET` will not work due to syntax issues and cannot work to update Excel workbook. It is not advised for us to recommend software, libraries, or tools on StackOverflow. After your research to find another method, make an earnest attempt, and ask specific questions regarding that attempt. Good luck!